# Generalization of Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, rolles-theorem

It is known that if a differentiable function f has two equal values f(a)=f(b) , then there is a value f(c) between them which is a maximum or minimum for that interval. However, if the one sided derivatives at any x between a and b are not infinite, nor equal, what could be said about the one sided derivatives in c? Could it be said that it is greater or lower than 0?

Comment: This is what i want to know. I read somewhere that f'(c) would be <=0, but there is no proof for that.

Comment: yes. i wanted to know what could be said about the lateral derivatives, but i haven't operated with symmetric derivatives before.

Comment: What are you trying to imply with the phrase "later derivatives"? Are you referring to second, third order derivatives?

Comment: i wrote lateral derivatives. they are the limits from left and right.